# How to debug batch query in Kapacitor

Tags: kapacitor, chronograf

As I understand in log we can see only discrete values and can not see table of values in series

with any aggregation functions

```
batch
    |query('''SELECT sum("gauge") ***  ''')
    ***
    |mean('sum_gauge')
    |log()
```

log() return Kapacitor point with value

but without:

```
batch
    |query('''SELECT sum("gauge") ***  ''')
        .period(1h)
        .every(10s)
        .align()
        .groupBy(time(15m),'host')
        .fill(0)
    |log()
```

show only

```
2018-05-10T13:19:20.084Z
kapacitor
begin batch
2018-05-10T13:19:20.084Z
kapacitor
batch point
2018-05-10T13:19:20.084Z
kapacitor
batch point
2018-05-10T13:19:20.084Z
kapacitor
batch point
```

according https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/blob/1.4.4.2/ui/src/kapacitor/components/LogsTableRow.js#L44
we will see that only "msg" field displayed in chronograf UI

but log has more info (you can see it using `kapacitor watch <task_id>`), for example:

```
ts=2018-05-10T14:50:40.011Z lvl=info msg="batch point" service=kapacitor task_master=main task=14860f8d-8b6d-48d4-a7fc-b5cbea717b37 node=log3 prefix= name=cpu group=host=*** tag_host=*** field_*=*** time=2018-05-10T14:50:00Z
```

---

Maybe someone know method or instrument how to debug such queries (batch)?

Because in other monitoring stack it's possible to create graph with preprocessed points in alert
example #bosun

[image]

"Alert rule builder" in chronograf looks like what I need but it has very limited functionality and you can not create sophisticated alerts (e.g with joins)

Answer (score 0):

chronograf >= 1.5.0 support `| log()` for batch query
https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/pull/3423